# Execute binary build with QT failed

Tags: c++, qt

I build my binary with `CMake` and I use `Conan` to manage my librairies. I compile it without any problem but when I want to execute it, this error occur :

```
QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./bin/babel_client
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/afoucault/Tek3_Epitech/cpp_bab
el_2019/build/bin/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstall
ing the application may fix this problem.
```

I only link with `Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::DBus`.

Comment: is qt installed in the host where you are executing the app???

Comment: QT is installed via Conan not in global on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but it seems you compiled in release.

If so, I think you may need to go into your ***Qt*** installation folder, find the ***plugin*** directory and copy-paste the inner ***platforms*** directory alongside the executable so that it will be able to find the plugins.

Example:

Let's assume you have Qt 5.12.1 installed in C: on Windows and that you uses the *msvc2017_64* compilation kit.
You'll have to copy the directory *"C:\Qt\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\plugins\platforms\"* along with your executable (copy the directory, not only its content).

Let me know if it does not solve your issue.